# Function formatting offset with sphinx and scipy theme

Tags: numpy, scipy, python-sphinx

I am using the scipy theme and sphinx with autodoc + autosummary.  When I build my documentation, I get the grey box area next to the parameter description.

[image: My Output]

Instead I would like it to look the example, where they grey box in on the word, Parameter.

[image: Numpy Example]

Any ideas where this setting is happening?

I am building on Ubuntu 18 (through wsl2), and windows 10.  Same thing happens. With Sphinx 2.4.4

For reference, default theme looks like:

[image: default theme]

Comment: The images depict the HTML output, and that is fine. But the title is misleading; this is not about syntax highlighting.

Comment: @mzjn sorry what is it called? I changed to formatting, but this is likely why I cannot find an answer either (don't know what it is called to search for).

Comment: It could be a CSS problem or perhaps a reST markup error, not sure. Have you tried other themes?

Comment: @mzjn I am not sure what I would expect from another theme, but I added what the default theme looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing, I also found that linux and windows were giving me different different results (just slightly), so I started comparing the html output, and found a small difference:

`<dl class="field-list">` vs. `<dl class="field-list simple">` above the Parameters section. This led me to a few github issues.

In the end, the answer to the question is that sphinx 2 changed to html5, based on this issue: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/6472

By adding `html4_writer = True` to the `config.py` file, the formatting works.

[image]